# Can not properly get the sum of rows. I'm not getting the sum of the correct rows

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
    int[][] userArray = new int[rows][columns]; //Establishing the bounds of the array

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //This is the loop to set the array values
    {
        System.out.println("Enter row" + (i + 1) + "values");
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) //Row value loop
        {
            System.out.println("Value" + (j + 1) + " is: ");
            userArray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(userArray));

    //This is the loop for for finding the sum of the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + "'s sum is" + sum);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            sum += userArray[i][j];
        }
    }
```

The output that I got was this 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
Row 1's sum is0
Row 2's sum is6

My output is only slightly off and I can not figure out how to get past it or find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + "'s sum is" + sum);
```

that is the first time you are implicitly declaring `sum`, so there is nothing to print but 0. That means the second loop is printing what you meant to output during the first loop. Hint: row 2's output is really the correct output for row 1.

Put the print statement after you set `sum` in your final inner loop.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 2):

You need to print it out after doing the summing

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        sum += userArray[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + "'s sum is" + sum);

    // and then set sum back to zero
    sum = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is the loop for for finding the sum of the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            sum += userArray[i][j];
        }
        // this should be after the sum has calculated
        System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + "'s sum is" + sum);
        // set to 0 for the next row
        sum = 0;
    }
```